# Xslt: add node to root element

Tags: xml, xslt

i have simple XML file:

```
<MyRoot>
   <Value key="TARGET">foo</Value>
   <Value key="MODEL">bar</Value>
   <Value key="MANUFACTURER">bla</Value>
</MyRoot>
```

and i want to add a Value node to MyRoot using XSLT. I can't figure out how.

Result should be:

```
<MyRoot>
   <Value key="TARGET">foo</Value>
   <Value key="MODEL">bar</Value>
   <Value key="MANUFACTURER">bla</Value>
   <Value key="NEWNODE">yeahIMadeIt</Value>
</MyRoot>
```

What i have so far is:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | *"/>
     <Value key="NEWNODE">yeahIMadeIt</Value>
</xsl:template>
```

But this puts the new Value node under the root Node :

```
<MyRoot>
   <Value key="TARGET">foo</Value>
   <Value key="MODEL">bar</Value>
   <Value key="MANUFACTURER">bla</Value>
</MyRoot>
<Value key="NEWNODE">yeahIMadeIt</Value>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're on the right track. You need to change your template match. Try:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="MyRoot">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        <Value key="NEWNODE">yeahIMadeIt</Value>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: yeah, thats it. One thing left: the new Value node got the attribute xmlns="". How do i prevent the transformation of adding this attribute?
<Value xmlns="" key="NEWNODE">yeahIMadeIt</Value>